# WinRT Xaml Two way Binding

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I just did WinRT xaml two way binding between Toggle button and bool dependency property. I am using Converter.

When I clicked toggle button , it invokes `ConvertBack()` that sets value to the source through property changed event.

Where I am making some internal calculations that may change the bool property so that the dependency property changed event is triggered.
This should trigger `Convert()` to set value to UI from source. But it doesn't. I need to know how to do this?

Comment: you set the binding mode to TwoWay?

Comment: can you show the xaml as well as your converter?

Answer (score 0):

`Binding`s listen for the `PropertyChanged` event to fire with the `PropertyName` set to the `Path` of the `Binding`.

Make sure what whatever you are binding to inherits `INotifyPropertyChanged` in some way (most ViewModels already do this), then whenever you change the value you should call your `OnPropertyChanged(*Property Name*)` or `RaisePropertyChanged(*Property Name*)` (for MvvmLight).